# In Windows 8, what are all the ways a program can be made to auto start on logon?

Tags: windows-8.1, autorun

Previously, I followed a blog post (that I've since lost the link to) to register a program to startup everytime I log onto my windows 8.1 VM.

Now, I want to stop it from staring up.

- I don't see a shortcut to the program in
  "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup".
- I don't see anything in the registry here
  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" or here:   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
- In taskmanager, under the Startup tab it says "There are no startup items to display"
- The parent process of the started apps appears to be explorer.exe

Where else can I possibly have registered this program to auto start when I log in?

Comment: run Autoruns, it shows all possible locations where tool can run at logon: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: Almost exactly nine years later, I'm here to say that I had the same problem, and @magicandre1981's comment is what helped. You should post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler can be set to run programs at log on, as well as timed intervals. The other big area would be System Services (`services.msc`).

In the event what you're looking for is not here, it's possible that more applications/processes get started from other programs, but you'd have to monitor to determine which applications are doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget AllUsers start menu location:

```
\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

There's also another registry entry (on Windows 7):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

There is another way to start a program that is not mentioned here. Dropbox auto-update uses it but I can't find out what it is.